# Google Sheets Query Including Blank Inputs

Tags: google-sheets

I want to run a query based off of several user inputs but I would like for the query to still run even if one of the inputs is left blank.

For example, my current query will run if the fields "Square Footage", "Property Type" and "ARV" are filled in but if I leave one or more blank it will not run. I would like for me to be able to leave them blank and it would then that field would essentially be a wildcard and the query wouldn't take that field into consideration.

My current query code is: =QUERY(Test!A2:L1000, "select * where L contains '"& E2& "' and K contains '"& D2& "' and D contains '"& B2& "' ")

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gU7HM.png)

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GmHT8JaLXuKrJCKWoGgL3a0J5BVCzIamvkHcj1aO3os/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is extremely difficult to write formulas when we don't have access to your sheet and data as described in forum rules. A picture is not much help, which is why the rules ask that people share a link to their sheet (or a copy of it) with share permission set to "Anyone with the link can edit."

That said, you can *try* this:

```
=QUERY(Test!A2:L1000, "select * where A Is Not Null"&IF(E2="",""," and L contains '"&E2&"'")&IF(D2="",""," and K contains '"&D2&"'")&IF(B2="",""," and D contains '"&B2&"'"))
```

If that doesn't work, please do share a link to your sheet or a copy of your sheet with permission set as described above.

Comment: I just added the link, sorry about that.

Comment: Charlie, I started in on trying to fix your formula; but nothing in that sheet or your original formula there matches the column layouts or pairings as you describe them in your original post (e.g., Test!L:L does not match the type of entry you're entering in DASHBOARD!E2, etc.). Your sheet names didn't match your post. You had a row of random numbers at the top of your Test page. In addition, you appear to be wanting to search by more than what you posted. For now, what were you trying to match in the last part the formula from your post here: ...and D contains '"& B2& "'...?

Comment: I can't imagine that you'd try to match EXACT ARV or Square Footage, either, if those were what you meant by the ...and D contains '"& B2& "'... portion of your post formula. Keep in mind also that the purpose of this forum isn't to do free work for people to the extent of building out full spreadsheets or functionality, but to help steer people in the right direction on a formula or approach. So keep that in mind as we go forward here. I can get you started, but you'll have to take it from that point and apply to your needs or expand upon what I start.

Comment: The original formula you shared was super helpful, thank you!

Comment: If the original solution I posted addresses the question in your original post, please mark it "Best Answer." It will help other contributors know that this issue has been resolved. In addition, study the formula I've left in your example sheet. It accommodates for three of your criteria. As I say, I didn't know if or how you would be trying to incorporate ARV or Square Footage, or whether number of beds and baths would also be included. I would recommend that you consider a low-end and high-end range in the search options for both ARV and Square Footage.